# How can I display popup window with select data from table that fetch data from ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in PHP and MySQL. I can display data in a table from MySQL database. That's ok. But what I want is to know how to display a popup window with selected data from a table.

I have done this so far, But what I need is when a user clicks or select the table row, a popup window must appear near the table with the select data.

This is my code, please tell me what I have to do:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Event Patrol</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br />
    <center>
    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect('I have', 'I have', 'I have');
    mysql_select_db('I have', $conn);

    echo '<table>';
    '<tr>';
    '<td>Event</td>';
    '<td>Record Date</td>';
    '</tr>';
    $sql = "SELECT * from people where PersonId = '".$_GET["PersonId"]."'";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result= mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$result["Event"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result["RecordDate"].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
    </div>
    </center>

    <div id="r" style="width:600px; align:centre"> </div>
    <center>
      <div id="content">
      <?php
      // Open database connection
      $con = mysql_connect("sql14.cpt1.host-h.net","rootaccess1","Screen_1");
      mysql_select_db("sentinelcrm", $con);

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM people";

      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">';
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<th>ID</th>';
      echo '<th>Event</th>';
      echo '<th>Control Room</th>';      
      echo '<th>Date</th>';   
      echo '<th>Site ID </th>';
      echo '<th>Action</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
      while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo    '<tr>';
          echo    '<td>';
          echo    $rows['PersonId'];
          echo'</td>';
          echo    '<td>';
          echo $rows['Event'];
          echo '</td>';
          echo    '<td>';
          echo $rows['Control_Room_ID'];
          echo '</td>';
          echo    '<td>';
          echo $rows['RecordDate'];
          echo '</td>';
          echo '<td><a href="" >';
          echo $rows['Site_ID'];
          echo '</a></td>';
          echo '<td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="opener"/>';
          echo  '</tr>';
      }
      ?>
      </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend jQuery's dialog. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Hi @Daan, Thanks for your reply. But the is no other way to use Popup Without JQuery?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in this code, and you should not put it live until it is fixed.

Comment: Yes of course there is another way you can program one yourself in javascript.

Comment: Hi @Halfer, Just as I said that I am a beginner in PHP. Please tell me how to remove the injection vulnerability into my code. or do you perhaps have a better way to do it! Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @Daan, I'm using a Linux server that doesn't support Ajax and some other advanced Java Query. I just need to know if there is a way to use a php or HTML code with CSS to display a popup with selected data inside

Comment: What you're saying isn't possible. It's a client side programming language, not server side.

Comment: @Daan, you may be right! would you please use that JQ Dialog box and some of my code to bring out an output that I need! Please, Thank you

Comment: _“Just as I said that I am a beginner in PHP. Please tell me how to remove the injection vulnerability into my code”_ – please don’t use “I’m a beginner” as a sort of cheap excuse. SQL Injection is a topic that has been broadly discussed and documented already, so it is your part to go and do your own research.

Answer (score 2):

You have a vulnerability in your code:

```
$sql= "SELECT * from people where PersonId = '".$_GET["PersonId"]."'";
```

Since you have not checked what is in this user input, a hacker could inject their own SQL and run that on your database in a way you did not intend. In the case of this library, the hacker cannot run absolutely anything, since it has to make sense in the context of your `SELECT` query, and (thankfully) this library does not support running many queries at once. That would allow them to issue a `DELETE` or `DROP` or something else destructive.

Nevertheless, hackers can modify `SELECT` statements to give themselves access to accounts or data they should not have access to. This specific query may not be security-sensitive, but nevertheless, security is a mindset you should have all the time, not only when you think it is important.

A *simple* way to remove the security vulnerability is to cast the number to an integer (assuming this field is indeed an integer and not a string variable). It's not ideal, but it will work:

```
$personId = (int) $_GET["PersonId"];
$sql= "SELECT * from people where PersonId = '{$personId}'";
```

That is now safe. However, it is recommended to take **both** of the following actions:

- Switch to a modern library such as PDO/mysql or mysqli, since your library is deprecated
- Use query parameterisation (search for it)

Comment: Thank you very much this your great Explanation! From today i know now how to save and secure my data. BUT Concerning my question, I really need an answer for popup windows or dialog box that will displayed the selected data from a table. Thank you in advanced.